# How to define application specific config file in Biztalk and consume it in specific application?

Tags: c#, config, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

Could you please help to define a define application specific config file in Biztalk and consume it in specific application? (We are using Biztalk 2016)

In my scenario we have 3 applications. Two are working fine in production environment, but one is breaking.

My problem is all keys are defined in BTNSVC.exe.config file globally (connection string as well as some dependent DLL version details), So we always tend to roll back all 3 application if any issue exists in 3rd application.

I tried to add some app.config files, but the application is not consuming it. In my c# code, keys are no getting fetched but in BTNSCV.confg is working with same code.

My expectation:  My requirement is to define 3 application specific config files (like web.config or app.config) and consume them.

Comment: That is a bit of a broad question.  I've seen some solutions where you have a helper class that will read a XML file to get config settings.  Other options include having BRE rules that will set the config when the Orchestration calls the BRE Rules. Also having SSO Configs read by a helper class. What exact problem are you having difficulty solving?  Can you show your code?

Comment: Also, any particular reason why you have tagged it with biztalk-mapper, as you have not mentioned anything about a map.

Comment: @Dijkgraff Thanks for response. I want to solve the problem of global config file. currently whenever i read from config file, my code reads from btnsv Gobal config file. but i want a application specific config file So that  extra keys  or config settings are not defined in Global config file. and i will move all those keys/sections to application specific file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it in the BTNSVC.exe.config file, but in separate files. you need to create a helper class that you can call, that will load that file, and fetch the configuration from it.   You could make this a class re-usable by all three applications by having one of the parameters the Application name, which would determine which configuration file to load.

Comment: Thanks for response, could you please  suggest any link or POC for this helperclass

Comment: @Tech_dopamine  https://www.biztalk360.com/blog/biztalk-server-best-practices-tips-and-tricks-13-stop-using-biztalk-config-file-to-store-application-configurations/